# Are all of the minor releases of PHP backwards compatible with each other?

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.3, backwards-compatibility, symfony-2.8

I'm planning to use Symfony 2.8 for legacy PHP versions. In the Symfony documentation it's mentioned, that the *minimum required PHP version for Symfony 2.8 is 5.3.9*. I'm afraid I'll have to take into account the systems with even older PHP versions also.

Can I safely assume, that PHP 5.3.9 is *backwards compatible* with PHP 5.3.0?

Comment: check http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php and you'll see, that you can't use it on lower than required version, as there are many changes from 5.3.0 to 5.3.9

Comment: You shouldn't use PHP 5.3 anymore it isn't supported anymore. If you have one lib that needs a newer version you have a big problem. And trust me the most of them need a newer version than 5.3.

Comment: @moped Indeed there are many changes, but I fail to spot the backwards-compatibility breaking ones..

Comment: @Stony I know that it's no longer supported and is outdated as hell, but I have no other choice. My employer demands older versions to be supported.

Comment: According to composer.json, even version 2.0 of symfony needs PHP 5.3.2. You could run the symfony test suite for version 2.8 on 5.3.0 and see which tests fail? It will at least give you something to discuss with your employer?

Comment: @AlexanderLomia what are dealbreakers? those functions that were added in later versions that Symfony may be using. The best you can do is to run tests as Ryan suggested

Comment: @RyanVincent That's a brilliant idea! Thanks, haven't thought about it.

Comment: @mblaettermann There are many clients who refuse to update their systems. I guess, there is nothing we can do about it without losing the client.

Comment: The mistakes were already done in the past: to give the client the feeling there is no need to update. Isnt Symfony2 an Update, too?

Comment: Losing the client is a win in this case.

Comment: @mblaettermann some of them have hundreds of legacy PHP websites on a single VPS. Updating PHP in is not possible, because majority of those sites will fall apart.

Comment: While 5.3.0 is not backwards compatible with 5.3.9, it is forward compatible.  I can understand the reluctance to upgrade but it won't break the existing code.

Comment: @Cerad I see. Does that hold true for newer versions also?

Comment: For the most part yes.  There are some functions which have been removed and some whose behavior has changed.  Need to read the upgrade notes and then determine if they impact the legacy apps.

Comment: @Cerad I see, thanks